# Why does no Python lib move the mouse in-games (CS:GO, GTA, etc.)

Tags: python, winapi, mouseevent

I tried out many Python libaries including but not limited to: PyDirectInput, PyAutoGui, Clicknium, Autoit, Mouse, PyGame and many more, but only win32api seems to work with win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE). The problem with that WinAPI is that it doesn't actually reliably work on all machines, e.g the mouse driver may interfere and make the movement sloppy and make it go all over the place, just like with a high sensitivity. With a high sensitivity it actually doesn't move where you want it to move it actually just moves somewhere random and flicks all over the place. I did an intense amount of research and found no real libary which could achieve actual mouse movement in a game like CS:GO other than the buggy win32api. Do you know any lib that might actually work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the python bindings for [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)? I've never really bothered doing anything serious with the python bindings, but AutoHotkey always worked reliably for me when I was doing similar stuff with games. It might be worth a shot. A quick search turned up two potential candidates:

- [ahk](https://github.com/spyoungtech/ahk): The more well-known of the two. Skimming through the code, it looks like it's translating the Python calls into an AHK script and running it with the ahk executable.
- [AutoHotkey.py](https://github.com/Perlence/AutoHotkey.py): Seems to embed python into AHK and executes your Python script after applying some extensions.

Comment: Just tested Autohotkey.py in CS:GO and it also doesn't seem to move the mouse, sadly